# Something similar to an abstract with a definition c#

Tags: c#, validation, virtual-functions, abstract-methods

Perhaps this is bad design in the first place, but I have an abstract base class, and it has a method `validate`

```
public abstract class abClass{
  string str1;
  string str2;

  public virtual bool validate(){...};
}
```

I know that every derived class will have properties that need to be validated, but I don't want to have to copy paste the validation for `str1` and `str2` for each abstract method.

I want to make sure future developers (including myself) will remember to include and fill out a validate method. From what I've seen, there's no way to give an abstract method a definition, or force a virtual method to be overridden.

So far all I've heard in regard to this is "you should let the developer choose what he/she wants to do." That's not good enough for me, it goes against checks and balances to help you not make mistakes. I don't mind if they actively choose to not have any implementation code, but if they forget, then that will cause a headache later when the derived fields aren't validated.

Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Make `validate` an abstract method instead of virtual? You can refactor out common logic.

Comment: So you want to force an override, and that override *must* call the base class? I don't think there is a way to enforce that in the language. Is that what you are asking/want?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I remember Martin Fowler discussing this...

Comment: [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html)

Comment: The problems you're fearing are real, and stem from the "call super" [tag:anti-patterns].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact issue is discussed by [Martin Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler) in his [CallSuper](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html) article.

He basically states that it is a bad practice or anti-pattern to *require* subclasses of your class to call the base class method when overriding:

> Call Super is a minor smell (or anti-pattern if you like) that crops up from time to time in OO frameworks. Its symptoms are pretty easy to spot. You are inheriting from a super-class in order to plug into some framework. The documentation says something like *"to do your own thing, just subclass the process method. However it's important to remember to start your method with a call to the super-class"*

His proposed solution is that the base class should take care of doing what's needed by itself, while letting the derived class only care about the derived class concerns:

> Instead the API should remember the housekeeping call for you. The usual way to do this is to make the handle method a [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), like this:

```
//translation of java code to proper C#
public abstract class EventHandler ...
{
    public void Handle (BankingEvent e) 
    {  
        HouseKeeping(e); //this is required by the base class.
        DoHandle(e); //Here, control is delegated to the abstract method.
    }

    protected abstract void DoHandle(BankingEvent e);
}

public class TransferEventHandler: EventHandler
{
    protected override void DoHandle(BankingEvent e) 
    {
       initiateTransfer(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, this is a perfect solution to my problem, and helps me avoid an anti-pattern. Usually i only get one or the other. Well done, and well backed up.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern:

```
public bool Validate()
{
    // Call base class validation
    if (!ValidateCore())
        return false;

    // Call specific validation code (overridden by derived classes)
    return ValidateOverride();
}

private bool ValidateCore()
{
    // Validate str1 and str2
    // ...
}

protected abstract bool ValidateOverride();
```

This way, derived classes have to override `ValidateOverride` (since it's abstract), and they can't forget to call `ValidateCore`, since it's called by a non-virtual method in the base class.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `abstract` to be able to use this pattern. You could define ValidateOverride as a "NOOP" procedure `protected virtual bool ValidateOverride() {return true;}`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, true, but making it abstract forces the inheritor to override it, which ensures they won't forget to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base good = new Good();

            Base bad = new Bad();

            good.Validate();

            bad.Validate(); // This blows up

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Base
    {
        public virtual void Validate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Good : Base
    {
        public override void Validate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Looks good to me.");
        }
    }

    public class Bad : Base
    {

    }
}
```

...although if it were up to me I would just define an interface with a Validate() method.

Comment: Why not make it abstract, instead of throwing an exception in the base implementation? Making it abstract would allow to detect the error at compile time, rather than at runtime.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yes, I agree that would be far superior. But also simply using an interface would yield the same results.

Comment: Not the same results: an abstract class allows you to provide some default implementation, whereas an interface has no implementation at all. The solution I suggest in my answer wouldn't be possible with an interface.

Comment: When I said same results I was referring to "error at compile time".